# pandas only saves first 100 entries of list when saving as csv with utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding, utf-8

My aim is to save a pandas data frame as csv file with utf-8 encoding. The values are sometimes long list (long > 100 entries). I noticed that the output of these lists gets restricted to 100 entries, followed by `...`. This problem only occurs when setting `encoding='utf-8'` in `.to_csv()`:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> d = {"row": {'column': range(1, 150)}}
>>> df_out = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df_out.to_csv("wo_encoding.csv")
>>> df_out.to_csv("w_encoding.csv", encoding='utf-8')
>>> 
>>> df_in1 = pd.read_csv("wo_encoding.csv")
>>> len(eval(df_in1.iat[0,1]))  # eval() to create list from string
149
>>> df_in2 = pd.read_csv("w_encoding.csv")
>>> print(df_in2.iat[0,1][-13:])  # last 13 characters
99, 100, ...]
```

Why is this? Would you consider this as bug? How do I get around (while still setting the encoding)?

Comment: Are you saying you see it in the file when you save it or just in the interpreter?

Comment: It's in the file as well. This code here is just to demonstrate that there is something going on because of the encoding.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing a list (if py2, range if py3) as a cell in a DataFrame? In other words, your `df_out` has a single row (indexed as "column") with 1 column (named "row") that contains an object.

Comment: Yes, it's python2. @IljaEverilä: Of course, this is just for demonstration. The DF in my application stores many more rows and columns (some of which contain containers).

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that Pandas has no idea how to serialize your containers, so you get varying results. I'd not consider this a bug, as a DataFrame is not really meant to be a container container. In Pandas' view those are just objects.

Comment: Maybe I misuse pandas by putting lists in a cell. But that's not the point. Changing the encoding alters the output, which it shouldn't.

Comment: As mentioned, this could be a serialization problem, and the difference in results might be either due to the fact that unicode chars take more space, and maybe pandas truncates over a certain size (not length, that is), or perhaps the string convertion function treats lists differently (e.g. str() vs. unicode()). The latter would be my guess. In any case try converting to string manually before writing to csv: `', '.join(list_obj)`. You can use the Series.apply method for that. Another option would be to wrap the list in a class with a manual implementation of the \__unicode__ method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it seems that Pandas treats lists differently in different encodings. In UTF-8 the lists get truncated at item #100.

To solve this, you can simply map list columns to strings manually, before exporting to CSV. In your example this would mean:

```
df_out['row'] = map(unicode, df_out['row'])
```

I mapped to the `unicode` function instead of `str` since I assume you are working with Unicode data, but the latter works as well in the example you gave.